# Any hint about stretching MkAnnotationView?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkpinannotationview

is there a way to stretch the bubble tha shows the details of an Annotation?
I need to use an accessory view and thus modify the size of the bubble.
Apparently it seems to be drawn in the lower layer and all views are drawn over it.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Hum, what do you mean exactly, the MKAnnonationView adjusts itself to the size of the text and also when an accessory view is set, so why do you want to stretch it yourself ? 
Do you want to set a `leftCalloutAccessoryView` with a large size and you would like the accessory view to adjust itself ? Is that the case you describe ?